Como hago que un imput tipo "file" sea requerido solo si otro imput tipo "radio" es seleccionado
Tengo este codigo que esta que me deja calvo, basicamente lo que necesito es cuando las personas digan que si tienen el documento social salga el input de cargar archivos(hasta ahora eso esta bien) y que este sea requerido solo si se selecciona la opcion SI, y si no se selecciona que no este el requerido
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
  <body>

<form action="guardar.php" method="POST">

<input id="tienesocial"  type="radio" name="social" value="Si">
<input id="tienesocial" type="radio" name="social" value="No">
                              
              
<label for="file-2" class="u-label">Foto de Social:</label>
<input id="filesocial" type="file" name="social" />
                             
                          
<script>
        
function mensajeChange() {
console.log("change");
const mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");
const filesocial = document.getElementById("filesocial");
console.log(boton)

if (mensaje.value == "Si") {
console.log("Es requerido")
filesocial.setAttribute('required=""')
} 
}
</script>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar Formulario">
</form>
</body>
</html>


Ajuste tu código, lo ordene y cambie la lógica de lo que quieres hacer, recuerda que los input radio no puede tener un mismo id ya que genera conflicto, de otra parte, es mejor ocultar el campo de upload si no es necesario y ajuste también una validación para que si o si seleccione una de las opciones antes del envió del formulario, prueba asi y me avisas:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="guardar.php" method="POST" id="miFormulario">
        <label>Si</label>
        <input id="tienesocial" type="radio" name="social" value="Si">
        <br>
        <label>No</label>
        <input id="tienesocial2" type="radio" name="social" value="No">
        <br>      
        <div id="upload" style="display:none">    
            <label for="filesocial" class="u-label">Foto de Social:</label>
            <input id="filesocial" type="file" name="social" />
            <br><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar Formulario">
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        // Manejadores para mostrar/ocultar el div en cambio de estado de los radios
        document.getElementById('tienesocial').addEventListener('change', function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                document.getElementById('upload').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('filesocial').required = true;
            }
        });

        document.getElementById('tienesocial2').addEventListener('change', function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                document.getElementById('upload').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('filesocial').required = false;
            }
        });

        // Validación al intentar enviar el formulario
        document.getElementById('miFormulario').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            const opciones = document.getElementsByName('social');
            let seleccionado = false;
            
            for (let i = 0; i < opciones.length; i++) {
                if (opciones[i].checked) {
                    seleccionado = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!seleccionado) {
                alert('Por favor, selecciona una opción.');
                event.preventDefault(); // Evita que el formulario se envíe
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>




MIL GRACIAS Hermano lo estoy probando y funciona, mil gracias!
